# OCaml: How do I compile/make a program which has file extensions .ml.x?

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have downloaded a project which contains the following files:

```
assert.mli
assert.ml
deque.ml
deque.mli
eventloop.ml
eventloop.mli
g.ml
gctx.ml
gctx.mli
gdemo.html
gdemo.ml
gdemo.mli
g-js.ml.x
g-native.ml.x
lightbulb.html
lightbulb.ml
lightbulb.mli
Makefile
paint.html
paint.ml
paint.mli
widget.ml
widget.mli
widgetTest.ml
widgetTest.mli
```

I can compile some of the files that do not depend on other files by doing

```
$ ocamlc assert.mli assert.ml
```

for instance.  However, `eventloop.ml` depends on `widget.ml` and `widget.ml` depends on `gctx.ml`.  `gctx` seems to depend on a module `G` which I believe is a graphics library.  When I peek inside `g-js.ml.x` I see it confirmed that this file is importing a fixed version of the graphics library.  However, I have no clue how to use this file.  I tried a few guesses in the terminal but to no avail.  One example guess was

```
$ ocamlc g-js.ml.x g.ml
```

I tried googling "how to compile ocaml ".ml.x"" but didn't come up with anything and I'm not sure if I should be searching for anything else, or if there just isn't much out there about how to handle these files.

I also tried in the terminal `$ make -f Makefile` and got the error

```
+ ocamlfind ocamldep -package js_of_ocaml-lwt.graphics -package js_of_ocaml-lwt -package js_of_ocaml -modules gdemo.mli > gdemo.mli.depends
ocamlfind: Package `js_of_ocaml-lwt.graphics' not found
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'gdemo.byte' failed
make: *** [gdemo.byte] Error 10
```

Looking up this error, other people found it fixed by updating OPAM's libraries and especially updating `cppo_ocamlbuild` but that didn't fix it for me.

---

Edit: After following some instructions in the comments, I get a new error message when trying to make the Makefile:

```
rm -rf g.ml
cp g-js.ml.x g.ml
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg js_of_ocaml -pkg js_of_ocaml-lwt -pkg js_of_ocaml-lwt.graphics gdemo.byte
Failure: ocamlfind not found on path, but -no-ocamlfind not used.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'gdemo.byte' failed
make: *** [gdemo.byte] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you check that the subpackage `js_of_ocaml-lwt.graphics` is installed with `ocamlfind query js_of_ocaml-lwt.graphics`? Otherwise, the extension `.x` probably indicates that the file is preprocessed with a custom preprocessor (and it is impossible to guess what is this preprocessor from the available information).

Comment: @octachron the query did not find the subpackage so I installed it.  However, it doesn't seem to have changed any of the error messages.

Comment: Do you have the same error when running `ocamlfind ocamldep -package js_of_ocaml-lwt.graphics -package js_of_ocaml-lwt -package js_of_ocaml -modules gdemo.mli > gdemo.mli.depends` independently?

Comment: @octachron So I'm a little unclear on exactly which "half" of the errors this is intended to resolve.  I ran this command and then ran `make -f Makefile` and got an error complaining about a pre-compiled file from gdemo (presumably created by the command that you wrote above).  If that's not the error this is trying to fix, I tried running `ocamlc g-js.ml.x g.ml` and it just doesn't know what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Like I said your *.x files require to be preprocessed before being compiled. The preprocessing step should be detailled in the Makefile. You should update the error message to reflect the new one.

Comment: @octachron I don't know what preprocessing means in this context.  Glancing at the Makefile, I don't know enough OCaml to make heads or tails of what it's doing.  So I still am not sure how I can and should use these files, either by compiling them one at a time or by using the Makefile.  In any case, I'll add the new error message.

Comment: The new error message is stating that you have a path problem: ocamlfind is not available from the make invocation. How did you install OCaml? What instruction did you follow? Note that https://discuss.ocaml.org might be a better help forum.

Comment: @octachron It's been a while since I installed but I believe I installed OPAM and then used that to install.  I likely just tried to follow these instructions: http://www.ocaml.org/docs/install.html and followed the Ubuntu instructions (using Linux Mint).

Comment: If you have opam installed, you can switch your opam version (for example to the last version `opam switch create 4.07.1` if your opam version is < 2 or `opam switch 4.07.1` otherwise. Then, you would be using an opam-managed ocaml, and it would be easier to manage the state of your installation.